# Why does 'redir' not work for me?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I am developing & testing with "remote servers"; using URLs for the remote system like "whatever.internal.ip:8080/someWebApp"

Unfortunately, I am dealing with new IPs every day. And changing the URLs within the application I am developing/testing is cumbersome. Solution: simply use an URL like "localhost:8000" and dynamically connect port 8000 to "whatever.internal.ip:8080". So, when I want to test with a different remote system; I simply change the "forwarding" configuration; but my application itself simply continues to use the same "localhost"-based URL.

I did some searching and found the "redir" tool; installed it on my system; and invoked it (as normal user) with:

```
redir --laddr=127.0.0.1 --lport=8000 -cport=8080 -caddr=whatever...
```

But, unfortunately; the tool does nothing; it prints its "help" ... and exits. No error message; and --debug doesn't print anything either.

Please note: the "URL" part is not important for the question itself; I just added it to provide some background. Actually my question boils down to: when I type in the above example on my Ubuntu 14.04 ... "nothing happens" (besides redir printing its options).

[ Finally; I successfully used "ssh -L" to achieve this; but I am simply curious why redir doesn't work. Besides, ssh obviously implies that I can do ssh to the remote system; whereas redir claims to be independent of the underlying protocol ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run:
`redir --laddr=127.0.0.1 --lport=8000 --cport=8080 --caddr=whatever...`
all params should be with **--** prefix and not **-** :-)

Comment: Ah, got it. But it would have helped if you had included: "you used - instead of --" ... I was staring at your answer for 5 minutes before figuring that I had a typo in my version of the command. So, redir is now doing something ... it prints "server: bind: Address already in use" ;-)